# Using pagination on a table in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I am trying to paginate a table which has 500 entries, with 10 entries per page.
To implement this I came across a GitHub [page](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination).

But it did not work. I would like to know what I am missing here.

Also my code ,

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title> Pagination example </title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
      <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="script.js"></script>

   <body ng-controller="PageDetails as pg">
     <table dir-paginate="comments in pg.comment | itemsPerPage: 10" > 
       <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>POST_ID</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>EMAIL</th>
            <th>BODY</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="comments in pg.comment">
         <td>{{comments.postId}}</td>
         <td>{{comments.id}}</td>
         <td>{{comments.name}}</td>
         <td>{{comments.email}}</td>
         <td>{{comments.body}}</td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <dir-pagination-controls></dir-pagination-controls>
   </body>

  </html>
```

script.js

```
  (function() {

      angular.module('plunker', []);

      angular.module('plunker').controller('PageDetails', PageFn);

      function PageFn($http) {
       var pg = this;
       pg.comment = [];

      details();

      function details() {
         $http({
         method: 'GET',
         url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments'
         }).success(function(data, status) {
         console.log(data);
        pg.comment = data;
        }).error(function(data, status) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    }

    pg.add = function() {
        pg.newComment.id = pg.comment[pg.comment.length - 1].id + 1;
        pg.comment.push(pg.newComment);
        pg.newComment = null;
    };
    }
    })();
```

Comment: what's in your script.js ? seems that u're missing the whole angular-utils library included

Comment: I have now included the .js

Comment: what do you mean "did not work"? you only posted pieces of a plunker, and a link to a directive that you are referring to in your HTML but don't appear to have loaded the script or the dependency for....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Firstly download the [dirPagination.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/master/src/directives/pagination/dirPagination.js) from here.
2. Include the dirPagination.js file on your page like :

> `<script src="~/Content/dirPagination.js"></script>`

3. After that add dir-paginate directive for pagination in script
   file.code given below :

> angular.module('plunker', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);

4. Then in tr tag add given line of code :

> ```
>  <tr  dir-paginate="comments in
>  pg.comment|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|filter:search|itemsPerPage:10">
> ```

5. Then add pagination control in your HTML page for putting buttons of First,Next,Previous and Last.Code given below :

   `<dir-pagination-controls
            max-size="10"
           direction-links="true"
           boundary-links="true" >
   </dir-pagination-controls>`

Answer (score 2):

If you study the [demo on the page](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wtkv71LIqUR4OhzhgpqL?p=preview) of [angularUtils](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination), you can see that they use:

1) include file with the library in html:

```
<script src="dirPagination.js"></script>
```

2) angular utility library is included as a dependancy in the application, see in script.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angularUtils.directivses.dirPagination']);
```

So you need to add those 2 things in your app file to make pagination to work.

Answer (score 2):

change

```
<table dir-paginate="comments in pg.comment | itemsPerPage: 10" >
```

to

```
<table>
```

then change

```
<tr ng-repeat="comments in pg.comment">
```

to

```
<tr dir-paginate="comments in pg.comment | itemsPerPage: 10" >
```