# Why bootstrap responsive table is not working with Angular 'dir-paginate'?

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Why bootstrap responsive table is not working with dir-paginate.
I have created a responsive grid HTML table by using bootstrap which is working with hard-coded data, but when my angular developer colleague used some 'dir-paginate' for retrieving data from the database then my responsive design code is not working when minimizing the browser shorter.

```
<div class="portlet-body flip-scroll">
    <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
        <table id="Tbl_SiteVisitViewAll" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed flip-content">
            <thead class="flip-content">
                <tr>
                    <th>S. No.</th>
                    <th ng-click="Sort('Active')">Attended By</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody dir-paginate="S in SiteVisits |filter : FollowUp |orderBy:'key':AscOrDesc | itemsPerPage:20">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{S.index}}</td>
                    <td>{{S.UpdatedBy}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" ">
                            Edit
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using the directive at the wrong Position. You want to repeat the `<tr>-element` instead of the `<tbody>-element`.

For more Information look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34392061/7225524

```
<div class="portlet-body flip-scroll">
    <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
        <table id="Tbl_SiteVisitViewAll" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed flip-content">
            <thead class="flip-content">
                <tr>
                    <th>S. No.</th>
                    <th ng-click="Sort('Active')">Attended By</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr dir-paginate="S in SiteVisits |filter : FollowUp |orderBy:'key':AscOrDesc | itemsPerPage:20">
                    <td>{{S.index}}</td>
                    <td>{{S.UpdatedBy}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" ">
                            Edit
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```